# Lua - How to do Internationalization?

Tags: web-applications, internationalization, lua

I built a Lua web application and it's become clear that I need to begin internationalizing ("i18n") it for my overseas customers.

**In Lua, what's the best way to internationalization my application?**

*I realize this is a significant undertaking, especially since some of my display is hard coded in HTML templates and some data fields are in my currently US-english oriented database.*

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: This is way to broad a question to answer. Narrow things down a bit. What is your application? What needs to be translated? What are you using to generate web pages exactly? And so forth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: added metatable stuff

> Would someone mind making the example code above a little more clear

Certainly.

In one file you define a `i18n` variable with the following methods:

```
local i18n = { locales = {} }

local currentLocale = 'en' -- the default language

function i18n.setLocale(newLocale)
  currentLocale = newLocale
  assert(i18n.locales[currentLocale], ("The locale %q was unknown"):format(newLocale))
end

local function translate(id)
  local result = i18n.locales[currentLocale][id]
  assert(result, ("The id %q was not found in the current locale (%q)"):format(id, currentLocale)
  return result
end

i18n.translate = translate

setmetatable(i18n, {__call = function(_,...) return translate(id) end})

return i18n
```

In the same file, or in other(s), you include the locales you need inside `i18n.locales` .

```
local i18n = require 'i18n' -- remove this line if on the same file as before

i18n.locales.en = {
  helloWorld = "Hello world",
  loginWarning = "You need to be logged in to do that"
}

i18n.locales.es = {
  helloWorld = "Hola mundo",
  loginWarning = "Debes haber iniciado una sesión para hacer eso"
}
...
```

Usage:

```
local i18n = require 'i18n'
require 'locales' -- if using a separate file for the locales, require it too

print( i18n.translate('helloWorld') ) -- Hello world
i18n.setLocale('es')
-- using i18n() instead of i18n.translate()
print( i18n('helloWorld') ) -- Hola mundo
```

Comment: kikito, many thanks for the detailed post. Just as a thought, it's it possible to not use the Translate table at all if instead the implementation used a metatable? That way, the usage would be as simple now as calling i18n('helloWorld'), instead of i18n.translate('helloWorld')

Comment: @nickb, sure, I've edited my answer to include it. I've also removed the local T.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful, but I found a bug, and I edited your code, translate should be called translate(...) to pass the id of the string to translate, cheers

Answer (score 2):

In Lua it's pretty easy to use translation tables. First write you code so that every string that needs to be translated is used via a function call, as in say `i18n"Hello World"`. Then write translation tables for the languages you want to support. For instance, `English={["Hello World"]="Hello World"}` (or add an index metamethod that simply returns the key, to avoid repeating strings) and `French={["Hello World"]="Salut le monde"}`. Finally write `function i18n(s) return Language[s] end` and so set `Language=French` when you need it.

Comment: So something like this? <br>
strings = {} <br>
strings["germany"] = {"Anwendung", "Fenster"} <br>
strings["english"] = {"Application", "Window"} <br>
language = "english" <br>
print(strings[language][1])

Comment: You will lose yourself in the numeric keys if you do it this way. One day you will see `language[1824]` and won't know which string 1824 is, and also your translation file will not be very readable. Better do what Luiz suggested - use the "default" english strings as keys - this way, you will always know what you are translating.

Comment: It is common to use enum-style names for language entries. For example: `English={ACCOUNT_CREATION_ERROR_PASSWORD_CAPITALS="You need as least 3 capital letters."}`. Although not nice on the eyes, it makes logical sense, and prevents typos such as "Hello world" not matching "Hello World".

Comment: But I'm a bit confused on how you would do that exactly. Would someone mind making the example code above a little more clear. Thanks in advance. Specifically, how would I easily "change" between using English vs French

Comment: @nickb, in my simple-minded example, switching between languages is done by assigning to Language` as in `Language=English; <using English> ... Language=French; <using French> ...`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in about the same way as in lhf's answer for [bib.lua](https://github.com/jpjacobs/bib), a project of mine, using a module defining a table of strings. I'd  just thought of sharing it, so you can see some code actually using something alike.

It's in bib/trans.lua.

Some things that might be added in my approach are:

1. Checking if the translation in use is complete, eg all strings defined in the
   *reference* language are defined in the language in use. Or better yet, even 
   check for all strings in the program to be defined.
2. A metatable mechanism on the different *non-reference* languages to print a 
   warning, and return the *reference* language label if it's not available in the
   language in use.

Those things aside, I was quite comfortable with it like it is. Only difficulties are if chunks of strings don't quite match due to differences in language structure. I wonder how to solve these.

Comment: Hi jpjacobs, how do you use the following file? https://github.com/jpjacobs/bib/blob/master/bib-0.1/bib/trans.lua

Comment: It's being `require`'d [here](https://github.com/jpjacobs/bib/blob/master/bib-0.1/bib/config.lua#L20). Afterwards you just pick a language out by using `strings=bib.trans.strings[en]`. Then whenever you need a string, create it in `trans.lua`, and use `strings.the_key_you_chose_for_your_string` instead.